# Store test dependencies in one module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a multi-module project with scheme like this:

- Module A
- Module B
- Module C
- Module ...

I have unit test in modules A, B, C.
I want to store all common test-dependencies like spring-boot-test, jupiter-junit-api in module B. How can I do that? Now I have common test-dependencies in each module. Could I store common test-dependencies in one module and add it to another as dependency?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to store all common test-dependencies`? The common test dependencies are?

Answer (score 1):

You can define all these common dependencies in the parent pom. they'll be inherited automatically if you'll use maven's inheritance of course.
So all your modules will inherit from a common parent (will have `<parent>` section) in their poms.

Note you don't need `<dependenciesManagement>` section, but rather `<dependencies>` section in the parent pom.

If you already use inheritance in all modules to inherit from `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you can take two approaches:

1. Make the parent pom inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent`.
2. Use Bill Of materials instead of inheritance:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thats not that I want. I have a spring-boot-starter-parent as parent. I don't want to add all common dependencies to parent.pom.

Comment: Please, read the second part of my answer I've offered two different solutions for having `spring-boot-parent-starter-parent`...